# Conversão automática de resposta em Wiki da Comunidade

Tags: debate, suporte, status-pronto, wiki-comunitário

Ao postar uma resposta para **[esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)**, como ia fazer uma longa tradução, resolvi postar o essencial, e depois incrementar à medida que fosse traduzindo os detalhes do artigo original (devidamente creditado). Para minha surpresa, na antepenúltima edição, ela foi convertida em Wiki da Comunidade automaticamente.

Só entendi depois, nestes posts do "Metão":

- [Why does Stack Overflow make all my answers community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203603/why-does-stack-overflow-make-all-my-answers-community-wiki)
- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
- [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits)

Como não houve má intenção da minha parte, só vi como alternativa **excluir e repostar**, mesmo com risco de não recuperar os vários votos que a resposta teve no dia, antes mesmo da conversão. Reputação por si só não deve mesmo ser a razão de se responder, mas não deixa de ser um incentivo. Só achei inadequada a conversão por ser uma regra que não tinha como eu adivinhar antes que acontecesse, visto que não temos uma documentação disso no nosso SO. E cá entre nós, dá um belo trabalho traduzir isso aí.

EDIT: cheguei a fazer o que o @bfavaretto mencionou no comment, de sinalizar a resposta, mas confesso que esperei poucas horas e achei melhor nao arriscar deixar passar muito mais tempo.

Assim, escrevi esta semi-pergunta por dois motivos: um, alertar os outros usuários desta "regra" do jogo, que pode até ser boa, desde que se saiba de antemão. o outro, pra realmente perguntar se isso é ou não útil no nosso caso, e "ouvir" a opinião de vocês sobre os benefícios de ter ou não essa regra em vigor.

Comment: Acho frustrante porque não tem um alerta e porque as edições foram feitas por apenas uma pessoa. Como isso pode virar comunitário? Enfim, você fez o que precisava. BTW, a resposta vai ajudar muito atrair usuários em buscas. Minha intenção é fazer perguntas que possibilitem ter conteúdo altamente relevante.

Comment: @bigown Acho que você entendeu bem o feeling. Um punhado de votos até volta rápido, mas a sensação de trabalho não reconhecido é que incomoda.

Comment: É comum no Stack Overflow sinalizar esses casos, e um moderador remover o status de wiki da resposta. Acho que seria a solução mais limpa, se o sinalizador for atendido com agilidade (o que não sei se ocorreria).

Comment: @bfavaretto até cheguei a "flagar" explicando o caso faz umas horinhas, pensei em aguardar mais mas achei que o estrago ia ser maior. No fim como não apareceu ninguem, apelei. Obviamente que agora que eu sei a regra, nem deixo chegar perto desse ponto. De qualquer forma, tá dado o +1 no seu comment, concordo 100% com o caminho que você mencionou.

Comment: Não sabia disso. Essa regra também afeta perguntas?

Comment: @VictorHugo Sim, acrescentei mais detalhes em forma de resposta.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uma pergunta ou resposta pode ser automaticamente convertida em Wiki da Comunidade nos seguintes casos:

- **NUNCA**

  - <strike>Se ou autor editou a postagem 10 vezes ou mais (edições que alteram somente o título ou tags não contam, bem como *rollbacks*).</strike>
  - <strike>Se pelo menos 5 usuários diferentes editaram a postagem.</strike>
  - <strike>Uma pergunta é convertida em Wiki se receber 30 respostas ou mais.</strike>

Antigamente, havia conversão automática de postagens para wiki nos casos riscados acima. Agora, somente o autor e moderadores podem transformar uma postagem em wiki. Respostas a perguntas wiki continuam sendo sempre wikis.

<sup>Fonte: [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (em inglês)</sup>

Caso sua pergunta ou resposta tenha sido convertida em Wiki e você não concorda com isso, sugiro duas atitudes:

- Sinalize a postagem com o tipo "outro", e explique o que está ocorrendo. Moderadores podem remover o status de wiki da postagem.
- Se não tiver seu pedido atendido, abra uma discussão sobre o assunto aqui no meta.

Comment: Eu ia abreviar "Wiki da Comunidade" para WC, mas achei melhor não :)

Comment: Todas essas regras ainda são aplicáveis nos dias atuais?(2017)

Comment: @Articuno Não, nem nos dias atuais (2018). Atualizei :)