# Sugestão de alteração de texto obsoleto das páginas de edição e posts Wiki

Tags: bug, status-pronto, central-de-ajuda

Na página de [Editar perguntas e respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> ... ***Um excesso de edições também pode forçar uma
>   publicação para o [modo wiki da comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)***...

Mas segundo [essa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/579/149882), isso não ocorre mais.

Nessa página [modo wiki da comunidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) está escrito:

> ***Também há várias formas de fazer uma pergunta ou resposta entrar
>   automaticamente no modo de wiki da comunidade***. Nos seguintes casos,
>   acreditamos que a publicação é de fato wiki:
>
> - o corpo da publicação foi editado por pelo menos 5 usuários diferentes
> - a publicação foi editada 10 vezes pelo proprietário original
> - você responde a uma pergunta marcada como wiki da comunidade
> - uma pergunta gera mais de 30 respostas

A sugestão é retirar (ou substituir) os trechos que foram destacados dentro das citações. Parece que o restante está correto.

Comment: De fato precisa mudar, [em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) não tem esse bloco todo. Não temos acesso a isso, preciso pedir para um CM.

Comment: @Maniero nem na [página de edição](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), tem o bloco mas não aquele trecho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na página das edições, tirei a porção realçada, e substituí pela tradução do texto presente na versão inglesa actual:

> Por favor tenha isto em conta e faça edições úteis, de modo a que atenção seja trazida para algo substancial.

E fiz o mesmo na página das publicações wiki, removendo a captura de ecrã e toda a porção citada nesta pergunta.